# Black cocos2d spritesheet in iPhone4

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I've got a weird issue that is reported by one of my app users. My app is using UIKit and Cocos2d (the latter for basically just one scene, the rest is all UIKit). The CC scene uses a 2048x2048 spritesheet. The user says that on his iPhone4 running iOS6, the sprites appear black. The app works, no crashes or anything.

I have an iPhone4S to test on hand and all works fine. Looking at the specs, the IPhone4 should be able to support this size for a spritesheet. Only the iPhone3G is not able to, according to the specs (1024x1024 max. size for spritesheets it seems). But since the user is saying that he is running iOS6, he can't be using a 3G, right?

So I'm baffled. He's the only one reporting this issue, too. Is there anything else that could be causing memory or other issues and cause a black spritesheet in an iPhone4?

Comment: ignore the report until someone else reports the same issue. It may as well be a defective, or jailbroken device or a simple reboot could fix it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, good to know. I wasn't sure if these could have that kind of effect on loading the spritesheet.

Comment: The only thing I can remotely think of that might cause this is if your spritesheet is a jpeg?  Cocos will consume more memory to do so and may cause such visual issues at least for 1.x not sure about 2.x.  I'm pretty sure I saw something like this a year and a half ago when me and my team were using jpegs.

Comment: Thanks Rob. It's not a jpeg (it's png w/plist made in Zwoptex) and I am running 2.x., however.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that that it works on any actual iPhone 4? It would be good to check if you don't. :-)